# Why a fast function becomes slow when inside ANY?

Tags: performance, postgresql

I have a function that returns an array of integers. If I call:

```
select getmun_gaz(12554)
```

it returns an 'integer[]' in 33 ms:

```
{1547,1564}
```

Exactly the same result I get with:

```
select array[1547,1564]
```

The same type (integer[]), the same values ({1547,1564}), only a slight time difference. So, why this works instantly:

```
select *
from loc
where id = any(array[1547,1564])
```

but this takes more than 2 minutes?

```
select *
from loc
where id = any(getmun_gaz(12554))
```

I will post the contents of the function and the structure of the tables if needed. The table from where this data comes is indeed large, but this made no difference in the beginning, so why it does in the end?

The function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getmun_gaz(gaz_id integer)
  RETURNS integer[] AS
$BODY$
with recursive locpais as (
    select l.id, l.nome, l.tipo tid, lt.tipo, lp.pai, 1 as profund
    from loc l
    left join locpai lp on lp.loc = l.id
    left join loctipo lt on lt.id = l.tipo
    where l.id = gaz_id
    union
    select l.id, l.nome, l.tipo tid, lt.tipo, lp.pai, profund+1
    from loc l
    left join locpai lp on lp.loc = l.id
    left join loctipo lt on lt.id = l.tipo
    join locpais p on (l.id = p.pai)
)
select array_agg(id) from locpais
where tid = 8
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE sql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```

I'll add the table structures later, if needed. Gotta go now.

Comment: What is `getnum_gaz()`?  Yes, you should post that function, because of course nobody here knows what's in it.

Comment: Try to declare your function as `STABLE` or `IMMUTABLE` [read here why](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-createfunction.html)

Comment: Looks like you solved it, @Abelisto. Post this as an answer, if it works the green check mark is yours.

Comment: @Rodrigo It seems that the right answer already here :) Just select the switch more appropriate for your function (it must be `STABLE` IMO).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because of your function's [volatility](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xfunc-volatility.html).

Declaring a function as `VOLATILE` tells Postgres that it has side-effects, and/or its value changes every time you call it (e.g. `random()`). This means that in your query, Postgres has to call it once for every single row in the `loc` table, and can't use an index on `id` to speed things up.

If your function only contains `SELECT`s, with no calls to other `VOLATILE` functions, then you can declare it as `STABLE`. This tells Postgres that the result will stay the same when called multiple times within a single query; the query planner can now call it once at the start and re-use the value for each `id` comparison, and can also optimimise away most of these comparisons by using an index.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with second one is if function isnt `IMMUTABLE` db need to calculate his value for each row

At difference with `any(array[1547,1564])` is a constant.

Comment: Why the whole table? getmun_gaz(12554) returns only two values, and really fast! There's something in the underlying logic that I still didn't get.

Comment: Yes I tought you was comparing different things, the problem is if you function isnt `INMMUTABLE` db has to calculate it for each row. Instead `array[]` is a constant.